# Excel visiual basic: increment trouble

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a code that, upon each click it'll add a number to a list, that number is copied from one sheet and is pasted on another workbook. The problem i am running into is the increment coding. I've tried { activecell = activecell + 1 } but it is adding the numbers in a descending order i.e. 7,6,5,4 and etc.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xzhB.png)

```
`Sub FILER()
workbooks.open("LOG")
Activeworkbooks.windows(1)visible=false
range("A3").activate
For Each Cell In Worksheets("LOG1").range("A3:A10")
If Cell.value > 0 
ActiveCell.offset(1,0).select
ElseIf Cell.Value= 0 then
activeCell.offset(1) = ActiveCell + 1
End IF
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It might help to post the code as text rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You go through the cells within a range, no need to select cells explicitly. Avoid using `.Activate` and `.Select`. You only increment the cell values if the cell value is 0.

-> clean up and shorten that code and post it into your question.